# Jade template inheritance block content not working

Tags: templates, node.js, express, pug

I have layout.jade:

```
html
include includes/head  
body
 header
  h1 Jumplink design
  p web design+creative solutions
 include includes/nav
    block content
```

and my about.jade which is supposed to extend the layout gets parsed but nothing shows.

```
extends layout

block content
h3 About me
```

In my navigation, I have a link to about.jade.I don't know what's going on, nothing works.

Comment: Ok, I m really a Linux newbie. The problem was my file permissions of the folder where the views are.oops..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish I could close this question. The problem was that my file permissions where not the same on all the files.